# PowerBI new Embedding Features

Tags: azure, powerbi

I'm looking at the new Embedding capabilities in Power BI. MS has depriciated the Power BI Embedded service in Azure and replaced with an updated services that is not clear on how it is actually to be used. I am looking at the embedding site:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embedding/

The site gives generlaizations and is unclear on how you actually configure an external (to Power BI) [WEB] application to interface with a Power BI workspace. A concept of Power BI App comes up but is not specified as being required for embedding (at least from what I can tell). The documentation is poorly put together and seems very incomplete. So has anyone figured out how to use embedding with the new Power BI version?

The following is an example MS put out for embedding. The part I am looking at is the App Owns Data example. Unfortunately I could not get it to work. Again documentation is incomplete:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples

Update:

The Power BI system [appears] to work on top of Azure Active Directory. It is stipulated that an AAD has to be configured to work with the app -- but unclear what they mean by app -- The AAD app is configured to allow access to the Power BI Service. The user used to access must be a user in the AAD. I did all that and [using MS embedded Power BI example] I get the following error:

unauthorized_client
error_description:"AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '183c54e1-bcc0-459a-89e5-302336606ab5' 
was not found in the directory

It unclear what is failing. The ID specified was the ID created when creating the APP in AAD - so not sure what is mean by not in directory.

Comment: Better try it here: http://community.powerbi.com/

Comment: Yes I saw that site - but I'm not a fan of MS based forums. Anytime I use I get a response that does not answer my question - then is marked as Answered

Comment: this is an excellent start<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480532/embed-power-bi-report-in-asp-net-core-website

Answer (score 0):

Found that the erros don't really clearly identify what is going wrong. In the end I found that I missed a step in the Application configuration step. A step to set the options for Power BI is identified:

[image: Power BI Azure Config]

Selecting the options do not specify they have been approved. This requires a second step (which I overlooked because the option selection was unclear). The second step sets the options as being active:

[image: Power BI Permission Granting]

The Grant Permission operation is required in order for the Power BI service to be usable (on the app [id] in the tenant).

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory(AAD) is cloud based identity provider which helps users sign in and access resources. First you need to register your application in AAD to establish an identity for your application and specify permissions to Power BI REST resources. When we register an application, such as a console app or a website, we receive an identifier, which is used by the application to identify themselves to the users that they're requesting permissions. There are two ways to register your application. The first is with the Power BI App Registration Tool, or you can do it directly within the Azure portal. The Power BI App Registration Tool is more convenient to use since there are just a few fields to complete. Use the Azure portal if want to make changes to the app.

There are two types of applications which you can register in AAD.

**Native :**

You plan on creating an application that is designed for your customers using a master user account (a Power BI Pro license used for signing in to Power BI) to authenticate.

**Server-side web application :**

You plan on creating an application designed for your organization or You plan on creating an application designed for your customers using service principal to authenticate or You plan on creating web apps or web APIs.

After registering the application you need to grant permissions to your application using azure portal. Login to azure portal and go to the Azure Active Directory > App registrations > Click on your application > Settings > Required permissions > Grant permissions.

After that you can get an access token to authenticate your application. According to the types of the registered application(Native or Web) there are two seperate ways to get access token from registered application on AAD. The difference is there is a client secret in web application that we can create using azure portal.

Hope you got a solution. If need further details feel free to comment.