# Embed Power BI Report In ASP.Net Core Website

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I have an ASP.Net core 1.1 website and I want to embed power BI reports into the site.

Azure Hosted Data documentation: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embed-sample-app-owns-data/

Using the **App Owns Data** sample found at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples I have a working embedded reports solution using the sample. However, the sample project is running on .Net Framework 4.5.2 and When trying to migrate the solution into my .Net core application I have migrated the code however the ActiveDirectorylibrary (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectorylibrary) in .Net Core does not contain a method for UserPasswordCredential

```
        var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);
```

The solution that I found recommended online for ASP.Net core is to use a tag helper however now that the Power BI Embedded and Power BI service have converged with the new arrival of Power BI Premium I dont think think  this solutions is possible due to the depencency on token authentication for the App Hosted data.

Full Report Controller Method:

```
            public class ReportController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly string Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pbiUsername"];
        private static readonly string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pbiPassword"];
        private static readonly string AuthorityUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authorityUrl"];
        private static readonly string ResourceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["resourceUrl"];
        private static readonly string ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientId"];
        private static readonly string ApiUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiUrl"];
        private static readonly string GroupId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["groupId"];

    public async Task<ActionResult> EmbedReport()
    {
        // Create a user password cradentials.
        var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);

        // Authenticate using created credentials
        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
        var authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, credential);

        if (authenticationResult == null)
        {
            return View(new EmbedConfig()
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Authentication Failed."
            });
        }

        var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

        // Create a Power BI Client object. It will be used to call Power BI APIs.
        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
        {
            // Get a list of reports.
            var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(GroupId);

            // Get the first report in the group.
            var report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();

            if (report == null)
            {
                return View(new EmbedConfig()
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Group has no reports."
                });
            }

            // Generate Embed Token.
            var generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");
            var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(GroupId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

            if (tokenResponse == null)
            {
                return View(new EmbedConfig()
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "Failed to generate embed token."
                });
            }

            // Generate Embed Configuration.
            var embedConfig = new EmbedConfig()
            {
                EmbedToken = tokenResponse,
                EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl,
                Id = report.Id
            };

            return View(embedConfig);
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

Adding a reference to .Net Framework 4.6.1 in the .Net Core project to expose the .Net Framework and allow the use of the .Net equivalent of the IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory but that did not seem to help.

How can I fix the library issue and embedding in .Net core?

### EDIT - Answer

Based off of the answer provided by @Fei Xue I wrote an HTTP helper class that performed a post to the API. Based off of the returned JSON I create an object and used the now available authentication token

Helper Class:

```
  #region Settings

    public static string BaseUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> content)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient
        {
            Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
            BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
        };

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json");

        if (content == null)
        {
            content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);

        var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, encodedContent);

        return result;
    }
```

Object:

```
 public class AAD
{
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string ext_expires_in { get; set; }
    public string expires_on { get; set; }
    public string not_before { get; set; }
    public string resource { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
}
```

Call from the controller:

```
            var url = APIHelper.BaseUrl;
        var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        content["grant_type"] = "password";
        content["resource"] = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
        content["username"] = "<username>";
        content["password"] = "<password>";
        content["client_id"] = "<clientid>";

        var response = await APIHelper.MakeAsyncRequest(url, content);
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var AAD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AAD>(result);
```

Comment: can you please put your full final controller code in? im trying to do the same thing - your work is excellent however i think im missing a piece or 2

Comment: @toy, apologies regarding the delayed response. I unfortunately, don't think I have the source code anymore, will need to take a look at my archives and get back to you

Comment: no worries - i figured out the missing piece was that the endpoint had changed from the orig code (ie, the stuff before yours) and i didnt catch it but now all is well - thank you

Comment: Check this post out: [Embedded Power BI reports with ASP.NET Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-power-bi-embedded)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The resource owner password credentials flow is not supported for the .Net core for Active Directory Authentication Library.

As a workaround, you can compose the HTTP request directly. Here is a example for your reference:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=password
&resource={resource}
&username={username}
&password={password}
&client_id={clientid}
&client_secret={client_secret}//if it is confidential app
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how many more folks will come across this question in regards to adapting the PowerBI embedded App-Owns-Data sample code to .Net core, but I was able to successfully get things up and running by way of melding Chad's sample classes with the code from [this post from the powerBI community.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Embed-Power-BI-dashboard-in-ASP-Net-core/td-p/273279)

The key (for me at least) was following the suggestion within the PowerBI post to swap this code in the original sample:

```
var credential = new UserPasswordCredential(Username, Password);
// Authenticate using created credentials
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthorityUrl);
var authenticationResult = await 
authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUrl, ClientId, credential);
```

with this bit (AAD being the returned object from Chad's sample):

```
var authenticationResult = AAD;
```

which also provides an actual embed token without calling UserPasswordCredential.

Full controller code below, hopefully it can save someone else a few hours of digging. Thanks Chad and Fei Xue for the sample! Cheers.

```
public class DashboardController : Controller
{

    private static readonly string Username = "yourUN";
    private static readonly string Password = "yourPW";
    private static readonly string AuthorityUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/";
    private static readonly string ResourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
    private static readonly string ClientId = "yourClientId";
    private static readonly string ApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com";
    private static readonly string GroupId = "yourGroupId";
    private static readonly string ReportId = "yourReportId";


    public class APIHelper 
    {
        #region Settings

        public static string BaseUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";
            }
        }

        #endregion

        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> content)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0),
                BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
            };

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "application/json");

            if (content == null)
            {
                content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            }

            var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(content);

            var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, encodedContent);

            return result;
        }    
    }


    public class AAD
    {
        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("scope")]
        public string Scope { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("experies_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ext_experies_in")]
        public int ExtExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("experies_on")]
        public int ExpiresOn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("not_before")]
        public int NotBefore { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("resource")]
        public Uri Resource { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }




    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string username, string roles)
    {
        var url = APIHelper.BaseUrl;
        var content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        content["grant_type"] = "password";
        content["resource"] = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
        content["username"] = Username;
        content["password"] = Password;
        content["client_id"] = ClientId;

        var response = await APIHelper.MakeAsyncRequest(url, content);
        var tokenresult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var AAD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AAD>(tokenresult);

        var result = new EmbedConfig();
        try
        {
            result = new EmbedConfig { Username = username, Roles = roles };
            var error = GetWebConfigErrors();
            if (error != null)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = error;

                return View(result);
            }

            // Create a user password cradentials.
            var authenticationResult = AAD;

            if (authenticationResult == null)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = "Authentication Failed.";
                return View(result);
            }

            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

            // Create a Power BI Client object. It will be used to call Power BI APIs.
            using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(ApiUrl), tokenCredentials))
            {
                // Get a list of reports.
                var reports = await client.Reports.GetReportsInGroupAsync(GroupId);

                Report report;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReportId))
                {
                    // Get the first report in the group.
                    report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault();
                }

                else
                {
                    report = reports.Value.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == "3a447f03-ad31-4e78-a3f1-2a6c008fcd8e");
                }

                if (report == null)
                {
                    result.ErrorMessage = "Group has no reports.";
                    return View(result);
                }

                var datasets = await client.Datasets.GetDatasetByIdInGroupAsync(GroupId, report.DatasetId);
                result.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired = datasets.IsEffectiveIdentityRequired;
                result.IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired = datasets.IsEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired;
                GenerateTokenRequest generateTokenRequestParameters;
                // This is how you create embed token with effective identities

                generateTokenRequestParameters = new GenerateTokenRequest(accessLevel: "view");



                var tokenResponse = await client.Reports.GenerateTokenInGroupAsync(GroupId, report.Id, generateTokenRequestParameters);

                if (tokenResponse == null)
                {
                    result.ErrorMessage = "Failed to generate embed token.";
                    return View(result);
                }

                // Generate Embed Configuration.
                result.EmbedToken = tokenResponse;
                result.EmbedUrl = report.EmbedUrl;
                result.Id = report.Id;

                return View(result);

            }
        }
        catch (HttpOperationException exc)

        {
            result.ErrorMessage = string.Format("Status: {0} for ID: ({1})\r\nResponse: {2}\r\nRequestId: {3}", exc.Response.StatusCode, (int)exc.Response.StatusCode, exc.Response.Content, exc.Response.Headers["RequestId"].FirstOrDefault());
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            result.ErrorMessage = exc.ToString();
        }

        return View(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using your sample and I'm getting an error saying invalid_grant - Invalid username and password although that is correct.  Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Hi MAK, just to clarify, did you edit the information static readonly strings to reflect your powerBI account information? Also, to be clear, you would ideally implement a method to reference this information as to not have sensitive data within your actual code.

Comment: Yes I did replace the values in my code. Also, I'll use a different strategy for the sensitive data.

Comment: @MAK This is probably too late, but I had the same problems and ended up determining they were due to ADFS.  I posted a solution that is working for me on this thread.

Comment: Thanks @tpankake, was having a rough time trying to recreate the issue at this point (no longer have a powerBI account linked with the original code base I was testing on). Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solutions here and various other ones online for getting an embed token is aspnetcore.  I kept getting invalid username/password, but I found that if I used the .NET Framework example from Microsoft everything worked just fine -

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Developer-Samples/tree/master/App%20Owns%20Data/PowerBIEmbedded_AppOwnsData

So, I know my credentials were correct.  Finally, I ran the .NET Framework solution locally and watched my outgoing traffic with Fiddler.  I was able to see that there were additional exchanges happening because I was on a Federated AD tenant (ADFS).  I worked backward from there to come up with the following (working) code.  Hopefully it helps someone -

```
public class PowerBIAuthenticator
{
    private static OAuthResult _cachedResult = null;

    private PowerBIOptions _powerBIOptions;
    private ILogger<PowerBIAuthenticator> _logger;

    public PowerBIAuthenticator()
    {
        _powerBIOptions = new PowerBIOptions();
        _powerBIOptions.ResourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
        _powerBIOptions.AuthorityUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token";
        _powerBIOptions.ApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/";
        _powerBIOptions.ClientId = "azure-ad-client-id-here";
        _powerBIOptions.Username = "master-account-username-here";
        _powerBIOptions.Password = "master-account-password-here";
    }

    public async Task<OAuthResult> AuthenticateAsync(PowerBISecureOptions secureOptions)
    {
        if (_cachedResult != null)
        {
            var expireDateTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(_cachedResult.ExpiresOn);
            var currentDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.UtcDateTime;

            if (currentDateTime < expireDateTime)
            {
                return _cachedResult;
            }
        }

        OAuthResult authToken = await this.GetAuthToken();
        _cachedResult = authToken;

        return authToken;
    }

    private async Task<OAuthResult> GetAuthToken() 
    {
        string commonRequestGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        OAuthResult oauthResult = null;

        UserRealm userRealm = await this.GetUserRealm(commonRequestGuid);
        if (userRealm.account_type.Equals("Federated"))
        {
            XmlDocument metadata
                = await this.GetFederationMetadata(commonRequestGuid, userRealm.federation_metadata_url);

            string trustBinding = GetFederatedUserTrustBinding(metadata);
            XmlDocument trustDocument
                = await this.GetFederatedUserTrust(commonRequestGuid, trustBinding);

            var userAssertionNodes = trustDocument.GetElementsByTagName("saml:Assertion");
            var userAssertionNode = userAssertionNodes[0].OuterXml;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                string tokenUri = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token";
                var ua = new UserAssertion(
                    userAssertionNode,
                    "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml1_1-bearer",
                    Uri.EscapeDataString(_powerBIOptions.Username));

                UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                Byte[] byteSource = encoding.GetBytes(ua.Assertion);
                string base64ua = Convert.ToBase64String(byteSource);

                var tokenForm = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", _powerBIOptions.ResourceUrl),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _powerBIOptions.ClientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml1_1-bearer"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("assertion", base64ua),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid"),
                });

                var tokenResult = await client.PostAsync(tokenUri, tokenForm);
                var tokenContent = await tokenResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                oauthResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResult>(tokenContent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var result = await client.PostAsync(_powerBIOptions.AuthorityUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", _powerBIOptions.ResourceUrl),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", _powerBIOptions.ClientId),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", _powerBIOptions.Username),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", _powerBIOptions.Password),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid"),
                }));

                var tokenContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                oauthResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResult>(tokenContent);
            }
        }
        return oauthResult;
    }

    private async Task<UserRealm> GetUserRealm(string commonRequestGuid)
    {
        UserRealm userRealm = new UserRealm();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string userRealmUri = $"https://login.windows.net/common/UserRealm/{_powerBIOptions.Username}?api-version=1.0";

            HttpRequestMessage realmRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, userRealmUri);
            realmRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            realmRequest.Headers.Add("return-client-request-id", "true");
            realmRequest.Headers.Add("client-request-id", commonRequestGuid);

            HttpResponseMessage realmResponse = client.SendAsync(realmRequest).Result;
            string realmString = await realmResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            userRealm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRealm>(realmString);
        }
        return userRealm;
    }

    private async Task<XmlDocument> GetFederationMetadata(string commonRequestGuid, string adfsMetadataUri) 
    {
        string metadataString = string.Empty;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpRequestMessage metadataRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, adfsMetadataUri);
            metadataRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            metadataRequest.Headers.Add("return-client-request-id", "true");
            metadataRequest.Headers.Add("client-request-id", commonRequestGuid);

            HttpResponseMessage metadataResponse = client.SendAsync(metadataRequest).Result;
            metadataString = await metadataResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        XmlDocument metadataDoc = new XmlDocument();
        metadataDoc.LoadXml(metadataString);

        return metadataDoc;
    }

    private async Task<XmlDocument> GetFederatedUserTrust(string commonRequestGuid, string trustBindingUri)
    {
        string trustString = null;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpRequestMessage trustRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, trustBindingUri);
            trustRequest.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            trustRequest.Headers.Add("return-client-request-id", "true");
            trustRequest.Headers.Add("client-request-id", commonRequestGuid);
            trustRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue");

            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime then = now.AddMinutes(10);

            string trustBody = __federatedUserTrustBody.
                Replace("{messageGuid}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).
                Replace("{adfsUserEndpoint}", trustBindingUri).
                Replace("{SecurityCreated}", now.ToString("o")).
                Replace("{SecurityExpires}", then.ToString("o")).
                Replace("{tokenGuid}", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).
                Replace("{username}", _powerBIOptions.Username).
                Replace("{password}", _powerBIOptions.Password);

            trustRequest.Content = new StringContent(trustBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/soap+xml");

            HttpResponseMessage userTrustResponse = client.SendAsync(trustRequest).Result;
            trustString = await userTrustResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        XmlDocument trustDocument = new XmlDocument();
        trustDocument.LoadXml(trustString);

        return trustDocument;
    }

    private string GetFederatedUserTrustBinding(XmlDocument metadata)
    {
        XmlNodeList services = metadata.GetElementsByTagName("wsdl:service");
        List<XmlNode> ports = new List<XmlNode>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in services[0])
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals("wsdl:port"))
                ports.Add(node);
        }

        XmlNode trustPort = ports.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attributes["name"] != null 
        && p.Attributes["name"].Value.Equals("UserNameWSTrustBinding_IWSTrust13Async"));

        XmlNode trustAddress = null;
        foreach (XmlNode node in trustPort.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals("soap12:address"))
            {
                trustAddress = node;
                break;
            }
        }

        return trustAddress.Attributes["location"].Value;
    }

    public class UserRealm
    {
        public string ver { get; set; }
        public string account_type { get; set; }
        public string domain_name { get; set; }
        public string federation_protocol { get; set; }
        public string federation_metadata_url { get; set; }
        public string federation_active_auth_url { get; set; }
        public string cloud_instance_name { get; set; }
        public string cloud_audience_urn { get; set; }
    }

    public class PowerBIOptions
    {
        [JsonProperty("resourceUrl")]
        public string ResourceUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("authorityUrl")]
        public string AuthorityUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("apiUrl")]
        public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("clientId")]
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class OAuthResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("token_type")]
        public string TokenType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("scope")]
        public string Scope { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
        public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ext_expires_in")]
        public int ExtExpiresIn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("expires_on")]
        public int ExpiresOn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("not_before")]
        public int NotBefore { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("resource")]
        public Uri Resource { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
        public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }

    private string __federatedUserTrustBody = 
        @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:a='http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' xmlns:u='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
          <s:Header>
          <a:Action s:mustUnderstand='1'>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue</a:Action>
          <a:messageID>urn:uuid:{messageGuid}</a:messageID>
          <a:ReplyTo><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo>
          <a:To s:mustUnderstand='1'>{adfsUserEndpoint}</a:To>
          <o:Security s:mustUnderstand='1' xmlns:o='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd'><u:Timestamp u:Id='_0'><u:Created>{SecurityCreated}</u:Created><u:Expires>{SecurityExpires}</u:Expires></u:Timestamp><o:UsernameToken u:Id='uuid-{tokenGuid}'><o:Username>{username}</o:Username><o:Password>{password}</o:Password></o:UsernameToken></o:Security>
          </s:Header>
          <s:Body>
          <trust:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:trust='http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512'>
          <wsp:AppliesTo xmlns:wsp='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy'>
          <a:EndpointReference>
          <a:Address>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</a:Address>
          </a:EndpointReference>
          </wsp:AppliesTo>
          <trust:KeyType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Bearer</trust:KeyType>
          <trust:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</trust:RequestType>
          </trust:RequestSecurityToken>
          </s:Body>
          </s:Envelope>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with the following code snippets. You only need to replace your user name and password of your PowerBI account, client_id, client_secret, authEndPoint and create AzureAdTokenResponseDto class.

```
    public static async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
             {
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "<user name>"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "<password>"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "<client_id>"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "<client_secret>"),
      new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api")
   });
            HttpResponseMessage res = client.PostAsync("authEndPoint", content).Result;
            string json = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            AzureAdTokenResponseDto tokenRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AzureAdTokenResponseDto>(json);
            return tokenRes.AccessToken;
        }
```

Now you need to create AzureAdTokenResponseDto class as follows.

```
public class AzureAdTokenResponseDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("access_token")]
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    }
```

Please make sure to install Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package. It works perfectly for me with ASP.NET Core.

Comment: What should be the IDeal ouath End Point