# fully compatible powerbi.api package with aspnetcore?

Tags: asp.net-core, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

i was able to get the sample asp.net embedded powerbi to work with my reports
now i have to migrate it aspnetcore
i was hopeful when i saw this post - seeing that someone was able to get it done
[Embed Power BI Report In ASP.Net Core Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480532/embed-power-bi-report-in-asp-net-core-website)

so i:

1. started a new project with the aspnetcore
2. installed the powerbi package

now when compiling im getting this warning:
Package 'Microsoft.PowerBI.Api 2.0.11' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

i searched and couldnt find a powerbi package that was specific to aspnetcore
is there one? will there be a conflict crossing cores? or does it not matter?

UPDATE:
4.6.1 powerbi package does indeed work with aspnetcore 2
but looking forward to a powerbi package specifically coded for core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see this is just a warning, not an error. That warning appears because .NET Core 2.0 applications can use some Nuget packages which target .NET Framework 4.6.1 (or less). However, this inclusion might fail if the referenced .NET 4.x package contains some API not included into .NET Core/.NET Standard 2.0

So, my advice - try to run your application. If it works well at the first glance - then, most probably that PowerBI package does not contain any not supported APIs and will work well further. If it fails right at start - then you will need to wait for the release of the new version of that package which targets .NET Standard 2.0.