# authentication to embed powerbi into aspnetcore 2 mvc

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, powerbi-embedded

there is an excellent example for how to embed powerbi **App Owns Data** here:
 https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-embed-sample-app-owns-data/

however this example is for running on the .net platform
and some of the routines used in the example dont exist for aspnetcore

there is another excellent post about someone attempting to do the same thing:
[Embed Power BI Report In ASP.Net Core Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480532/embed-power-bi-report-in-asp-net-core-website)

as well as this one:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Embed-Power-BI-dashboard-in-ASP-Net-core/td-p/273279

however im having trouble even getting the stuff to authenticate
here is how my current code stands:

```
    private static readonly string AuthorityUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/";
    private static readonly string ResourceUrl = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api";
    private static readonly string ApiUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/";
    private static readonly string EmbedUrl = "https://app.powerbi.com/";
    private static readonly string ClientId = "xxxxclientid";
    private static readonly string Username = "xxxxusername";
    private static readonly string Password = "xxxxpass";
    private static readonly string GroupId = "xxxxgroup";
    private static readonly string ReportId = "xxxxreportid";

    public async Task<ActionResult> embed(string username, string roles)
    {
        var result = new EmbedConfig();
        try
        {
            result = new EmbedConfig { Username = username, Roles = roles };
            var error = GetWebConfigErrors();
            if (error != null)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = error;
                return View(result);
            }

            var authenticationResult = await AuthenticateAsync();
            if (authenticationResult == null)
            {
                result.ErrorMessage = "Authentication Failed.";
                return View(result);
            }

            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(authenticationResult.AccessToken, "Bearer");

            ... [the rest is post-authentication stuff, ie powerbi]
}

    private static async Task<OAuthResult> AuthenticateAsync()
    {
        Uri oauthEndpoint = new Uri(AuthorityUrl);
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.PostAsync(oauthEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("resource", ResourceUrl),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", Username),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", Password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "openid"),
            }));

            string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OAuthResult>(content);
        }
    }
```

where oAuthResult class is

```
   public class OAuthResult
{
    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("scope")]
    public string Scope { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("experies_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ext_experies_in")]
    public int ExtExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("experies_on")]
    public int ExpiresOn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("not_before")]
    public int NotBefore { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("resource")]
    public Uri Resource { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```

i know my credentials work
because i built the original solution in classic .net with them
and they worked swimmingly

now however in this version im receiving this response in AuthenticateAsync (only a portion):
"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n    Sign in to your account\r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n\r\n        \r\n            https://login.windows.net/common/jsdisabled\" />\r\n        \r\n        https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.7382.8/content/images/favicon_a.ico\" />\r\n    \r\n    "

which is obviously not a JSON response but rather the html for the ms login box
and indeed i managed to render the output and it looks like this

[image]

can anyone point me in the proper direction so that 
it authenticates properly and sends me a token instead of a login box?
thank you

**UPDATE**:
ive tried logging in directly through browser url
here is the url im using:
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize/?client_id=myid&grant_type=password&username=myun&password=mypw&scope=openid

does the url at least look correct for the non-sensitive info?
still getting the sign in box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use: AuthorityUrl = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token/"
Please see - [Embed Power BI Report In ASP.Net Core Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480532/embed-power-bi-report-in-asp-net-core-website)

Comment: dude - thank you - i didnt notice that the endpoints had changed from code to code