# Get auth token for Power Bi native app using Rest API for .Net core web app

Tags: api, asp.net-core, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have MSC 6 Web application (.Net Core 2.1) and wants to embed the Power BI report using REST API. I am easily able to embed the report in.Net 4.6 web app, but facing issues in .Net Core app.

I am getting issue while getting the auth token for a native app created on Azure. I followed example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480532/embed-power-bi-report-in-asp-net-core-website) but it didn't work for me.

- I have created the Power BI workspace on Azure and provided access to me
- Registered the new native app on Azure and provided the AAD & Power BI service access.

Anybody having PoC of accessing Power BI REST API for .Net core app? Please provide the pointers for this issue.

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: What "it didn't work for me" means? Please, be more specific. The question you linked already gives a POC code for this. Other PoC will not look any different

Comment: @AndreyNikolov - Thanks for quick reply. I have used the "MakeAsyncRequest" method (as per example in the example) that does not return the token. I am getting error as "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value". This is on statement `code`var AAD = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AAD>(result);

Comment: And what was the value of `result` in this case?

Comment: @AndreyNikolov - It returns the raw HTML with script tag. And thos are not having any token related information

Comment: @Rohan , you can use Fiddler or browser's develop tools to trace the request . The first thing is to confirm no error occurs  when requesting the access token .

Comment: @NanYu- it is giving me error as "**Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password**". But the credentials are 100% correct. This must be some other issue.

Comment: @Rohan what is the exact line your are receiving this error, please share the line. Did you add the account as admin account to your workspace? Also, go to Azure Active Directory -> App registration -> My App -> click <your app> -> Settings -> Owners and make sure the user has been added as an owner to the application.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - Yes I have Admin access. I have added my user as admin for this app registered in Azure. I am getting error when I give call for API using HttpClient, `HttpClient.PostAsync()` method

Answer (score 0):

My team had this issue. The AAD account could not follow through the authentication channels. However, we were able to make it work with a tenant account ( *tenant*@*MyOrgOnline*.onmicrosoft.com ).